# Change mailed-by header in PHP mail

Tags: php, email, gmail, header

I've configured several headers in the `mail()` function, sender name and other fields appear as set. But, in the gmail `mailed-by` field, I see the hostname of my server, even though I've set the Mailed-By header to be different... Is there a way to change this, or am I specifying the wrong header to effect the change?

Current Headers:

```
From: no-reply@example.com
Mailed-By: Example.com
X-Mailer: Example/1.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you post the headers you are sending it will be easier to diagnose the issue. But the header should be "X-Mailer" to set the application mailed-by field, as far as I know. If that does not work, post your current headers and we can help you further / better.

**EDIT:**

Doing some further research, it seems the 5th parameter with the "-f" flag would be the way to do it:

`mail($to, $message, $body, $headers, '-fnoreply@yourmailer.com');`

Is a possibility. That is generally an email address, so you would have to see what values it accepts etc. I found this information from the Joyent Discussion Board.

But reading that it may not be what you want.

> -fname      Sets the name of the `from'' person (i.e., the sender of the mail).  -f can only be used by` trusted'' users (normally
> root, daemon, and network) or if the person you are trying to
> become is the same as the person you are.

From the [sendmail Man page](http://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/man/sendmail.html). I will see if I cannot strum anything else up.

Comment: posted headers... i had assigned the x-mailer as the first thing, but added the mailed-by line on top to try overriding the gmail mailed-by. no go. :-(

Comment: Updated with an option to test, the 5th parameter of sendmail, "-f"

Comment: the 5th parameter `-f` worked for me, gmail no longer shows the 'mailed-by' or 'via' items

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like that mailed-by header was added by your mail transfer agent, or gmail, after it left PHP.  Sounds like it may be a security measure so abuse reports can be tracked down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been solved as it's old but I had the same issue on a contact page from my website.  We wanted club members to be able to use a form to contact the officers.  But I wanted it to look like it came from the e-mail address the user entered so the officer could respond directly.  I found this code and modified it for my site.

```
  $headers = "From: <$email> \n";
  $headers .= "X-Sender: <$from>\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
```

$email is the address the user entered.  I can't say I understand it all but it solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

You Cannot Set the Mailed-by option of your own.
you have to publish your spf record and should have DKIM signature for this.
For extra Information click on this link.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en